# How is a Javascript number stored in memory

Tags: javascript, numbers

First, we see the code below:

```
result = 0.1 + 0.2;     
alert(result===0.3);// false
result=100.1+100.2;
alert(result===200.3);//true
```

I believe that `0.1` and `100.1` (100+0.1) are stored similarly in memory, since the decimal is `.1` in both of them.

So, why is the result of the addition different?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is JavaScript's Math broken?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/is-javascripts-math-broken)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

They are not stored the same in memory: http://steve.hollasch.net/cgindex/coding/ieeefloat.html

0.1 in binary:

0.1 * 2 = **0** + 0.2
0.2 * 2 = **0** + 0.4
0.4 * 2 = **0** + 0.8
0.8 * 2 = **1** + 0.6
0.6 * 2 = **1** + 0.2
0.2 * 2 = **0** + 0.4
0.4 * 2 = **0** + 0.8
0.8 * 2 = **1** + 0.6
0.6 * 2 = **1** + 0.2

As you can see, after the 0.2 repeated the whole pattern (0011) will just keep repeating, so `0.1` is `0.0001100110011001100110011..`. repeating forever

To represent that in a 23 bit mantissa we have to shift it left until we have a 1 before the decimal point (after shifting the bits left 4 places and removing the 1 before the decimal we have `100110011...`) and then round at the 23rd bit, and we get: `10011001100110011001101`.

Since we shifted 4 places our exponent is `127-4` (127 is the 32 bit bias). 123 in 8 bits of binary is `01111011`, all that's left is the sign bit, which we know is 0 since 0.1 is a positive number. So each component of the 32 bit binary number is:

sign: 0
exponent: 01111011
mantissa: 10011001100110011001101

0.1 is represented as `00111101110011001100110011001101` in a floating point number.

Converting back we have to break it back apart and then convert the exponent back to a decimal integer (123). We shift the mantissa (with an assumed 1 in front) to the right (127 - 123 = 4) times and get : `0.00011001100110011001101101` then we convert this back to decimal:

```
0*1/2 + 0*1/4 + 0*1/8 + 1/16 + 1/32 + 0*1/64 + 0*1/128 + 1/256 + 1/512 + 
0 + 1/4096 + 1/8192 + 0 + 1/65536 + 1/131072 + 0 + 1/1048576 + 1/2097152 + 
0 + 1/16777216 + 1/33554432 + 0 + 1/134217728
```

Which if you do the math gives you something closer to 0.100000001, than to 0.1. That's because we rounded at the 23rd bit. 0.1 cannot be stored in binary since it repeats forever, so after the 23rd bit we have inaccuracies. When you do arithmetic on a number those inaccuracies are carried through, and the errors can grow to be much larger.

If you do the same thing with 100.1 you get:

1100100.0001100110011001100... repeating forever:

Shift right 6 times and removing the 1 before the decimal round to 23rd bit: 10010000011001100110011

Exponent is 127+6 = 133 (1000 0101)

Sign is 0 again, so you have:

```
01000010110010000011001100110011
```

Comment: but why the result of (100.1 + 100.2) is accurate??

Comment: In Javascript the casting between float-numbers and "Full numbers" happens automatically. Float-Numbers have the benefit, that they can show huge numbers but sometimes with loss of accuracy. It's generally forbidden to compare float-numbers as equal, because there might always be small differences. Use greather than or less than instead...

Answer (score 0):

In addition to Paul P.R.O's answer

This is not a problem with javascript alone. In C# double exhibits the same behavior

```
double a = 0.1, b = 0.2;
Console.WriteLine((a + b)==0.3); //Prints False
```

Hence,it is advisable to use decimal in c# for precision. For javascript you should use .toFixed to work with currency operations. For more inside into numbers in javascript check out http://www.hunlock.com/blogs/The_Complete_Javascript_Number_Reference#quickIDX0

Answer (score 0):

This is the IEEE 754 [<sup>wikipedia</sup>](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_754-2008) implementation result. There is not way to present every float point number, and it is present in **every language** following the IEEE 754 standart. This code snippet will have the same result in any language:

```
var sum = 0.0;
for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++ )
{
    sum += 0.1;
}
// sum = 0.9999999999999999
```

0.1 is exactly one of the numbers that do not have an exact representation [<sup>wikipedia</sup>](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floating_point#Some_other_computer_representations_for_non-integral_numbers).

C# has a special type Decimal [<sup>MSDN</sup>](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/364x0z75%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) which is appropriate for financial and monetary calculations, which internaly is a structure.